# Calling API end points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, api, endpoints

I have Json/GeoJson data, boat positions and headings, which is continuously updated on an URL.

I want to get get this data into QGIS.

I tried  OAuth2 in WMTS, Add Vector Layer (Protocol HTTPS) and ArcGIS REST Server Layer to get API end points (URL + token) to QGIS .

Seems this is not working. For WMS(Oauth2) I get message "Download of capabilities failed: network request update failed for authentication config" f.e.

Might this be possible at all with classical "Add Layer" methods or a python script is to be used to get this working ?

regards

Comment: Have you tried to load this as Vector Layer with protocole GeoJSON by giving the URI ?

Comment: I have tried but this URL has built in Authorization bearer . I tried pasting in it(Token) but it  is not accepted.

Comment: Even GeoJSON with OAuth2 authentication in the box below ?

Comment: If I select Add Vector Layer -Protocol:HTTPS- Protocol(GeoJson)-Configurations (I only see -Basic -type of authentication not Oauth2). Unfortunatelly

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check that, you're right, this kind of authentication accept only basic auth.